# stick UIView to bottom of parent UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I create some view

```
self.customView.frame = CGRect...;
```

add subview and change frame.

This work as I expect. (UIView stay stuck to bottom)

```
UIView *bottomSeparatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, -1.0f, CGRectGetWidth(view.frame), 1.0f)];
bottomSeparatorView.backgroundColor = DEFAULT_COLOR_PLACEHOLDER;
bottomSeparatorView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
[view addSubview:bottomSeparatorView];
```

but this doesn't work. (UIView out of view/hidden)

```
UIView *bottomSeparatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, -0.5f, CGRectGetWidth(view.frame), 0.5f)];
bottomSeparatorView.backgroundColor = DEFAULT_COLOR_PLACEHOLDER;
bottomSeparatorView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
[view addSubview:bottomSeparatorView];
```

bottomSeparatorView frame before resize customView:

```
{{0, -0.5}, {0, 0.5}} // 1px
{{0, -1}, {0, 1}} // 2px
```

after:

```
{{0, 99}, {320, 0}} // 1px
{{0, 99}, {320, 1}} // 2px
```

Comment: set height to 1.0 in second part

Comment: If it's a bottom separator wouldn't you want the y-value to be `view.bounds.size.height-0.5f`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the y-value of the bottom separator frame to `view.bounds.size.height-0.5f` if you in fact want it positioned at the bottom. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you're trying to achieve a true 1px horizontal line. I'm not 100% sure about this but it's possible that you'd run into a problem using `0.5f` heights on non-retina display devices. To be safe you could define the height first using the device `scale` property like so:

```
float height = 1/[[UIScreen mainScreen]scale];

UIView *bottomSeparatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, view.bounds.size.height-height, CGRectGetWidth(view.frame), height)];
bottomSeparatorView.backgroundColor = DEFAULT_COLOR_PLACEHOLDER;
bottomSeparatorView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
[view addSubview:bottomSeparatorView];
```